# Extract the only item from list in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

How do I extract the value from a list? For e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 4, 'Abc', 456, '[45.55%]'],
                   [2, 5.2, 'abc', 5, '[34.54%]'],
                   [0.2, 6, 'xyz', 65, '[12.21%]'],
                   [3, 4.1, 'Xbc', 23, '[99.12%]']], columns=['start', 'end', 'name','body_mass', 'budget'])
```

I can use the string replace function as shown below. But I am looking for a better solution.

```
df.budget.str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '').str.replace('%', '').astype(float)

0    45.55
1    34.54
2    12.21
3    99.12
Name: budget, dtype: float64
```

There is only 1 item in the list, if that matters.

Comment: I've provided one way, but it's not clear what you mean by "better": do you mean less code, faster, or more flexible?

Comment: @jpp There are 3 replace methods. I am looking for a way to reduce the chain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regular Expression:

```
df.budget.str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way using `pd.Series.str.replace` to remove %, `ast.literal_eval` to convert string to list, and `operator.itemgetter` to extract first item.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from operator import itemgetter

df['budget'] = df['budget'].str.replace('%', '')\
                           .apply(literal_eval)\
                           .apply(itemgetter(0))

print(df['budget'])

0    45.55
1    34.54
2    12.21
3    99.12
Name: budget, dtype: float64
```

---

Alternative method using regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in ('%', '[', ']')])

df['budget'] = df['budget'].str.replace(pattern, '')\
                           .astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['budget']=df.budget.str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '').str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
```

this will replace the whole column in your dataset

Comment: How is this different to OP's existing solution?